# Fix for blurry rendered font in browser on Windows

Tags: css, fonts, blurry

I have a pixelated font in one of my projects (like the one in the link down below) but Windows renders it blurry which is annoying because we want a pixelated font for this project. The issue is that all the developers on the project is using Mac so its hard for us to trying to play around with it to see if its possible to make it less blurry.

So my question is if there is someone out there with a Windows computer that could take a look at the link below and see if you can make it somewhat less blurry?

https://fj7o67.csb.app/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the font you are using is not working well with font weight.

Add this:

```
h1,h2 {font-weight:normal;}
```